# Why is spool not needed with Symfony Mailer 4.4?

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, mailer

We are switching from Swift_Mailer to Symfony Mailer. Swift_Mailer had the option so spool a message. I do not see this option in Symfony Mailer. I have looked thru the Symfony documentation and could not find anything about is for Symfony 4.4.

Does anyone know if the spool option is still available of it's not needed anymore - for some reason?

Comment: Because Symfony 4 has the Messenger component. You are supposed to use that if you want to send async emails. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#sending-messages-async

Comment: Clear and thank you. I overlooked this part.